# injecting ejs with a client-side variable

Tags: express, ejs

My express router is making available an object on my ejs template called inventory.

My client side is doing a ajax request that returns an object called result.

I want to put the value of result object into my ejs tag. How can I do this?

```
<%= inventory["result[x].variation_identifier"].price %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. The values inside the EJS tags are calculated and rendered as strings into the markup on page load. What I would suggest that you do is wrap this EJS in another element, then change that element's innerText in the callback of your AJAX request. In turn, I must advise you to avoid turning around and using hard-coded values in your markup to perform other calculations or requests.